# How do I avoid the 'NavigableString' error with BeautifulSoup and get to the text of href?

Tags: beautifulsoup

This is what I have:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin

url = "http://python.beispiel.programmierenlernen.io/index.php"
doc = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(doc, "html.parser")

for i in soup.find("div", {"class":"navigation"}):
    print(i)
```

Currently the print output of "i" is:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="index.php?page=2">Zur nächsten Seite!</a>
```

I want to print out the href link "index.php?page=2".
When I try to use BeautifulSoups "find", "select" or "attrs" method on "i" I get an error. For instance with

```
print(i.attrs["href"])
```

I get:

```
AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'attrs'
```

How do I avoid the 'NavigableString' error with BeautifulSoup and get the text of href?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to be `for i in soup.find`. If you're looking for only one element, there's no need to iterate that element, and if you're looking for multiple elements, `find_all` instead of `find` would probably match the intent.

More concretely, here are the two approaches. Beyond what's been mentioned above, note that `i` is a `div` that contains the desired `a` as a child, so we need an extra step to reach it (this could be more direct with an xpath).

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://python.beispiel.programmierenlernen.io/index.php"
doc = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(doc, "html.parser")

for i in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "navigation"}):
    print(i.find("a", href=True)["href"])

print(soup.find("div", {"class": "navigation"})
          .find("a", href=True)["href"])
```

Output:

```
index.php?page=2
index.php?page=2
```